# How to toggle Blockly toolbox

Tags: javascript, google-blockly

I am making a web based coding games, so I am using blockly so kids can drag and drop to program their games. I was able to customize few things on the editor using my own JavaScript and CSS. But I want the feature to toggle the toolbox, so there will be more space to see the blocks.

I tried hiding the toolbox with JavaScript like this.

```js
$(".blocklyToolboxDiv").css("display", "none");
```

But the problem is whenever I drag a block to that empty space it got removed. Is there any way I could tell blockly to do not remove blocks dragged over the toolbox?

[image: blockly toolbox image]

Answer (score 0):

You may access the `toolbox_` element of the workspace variable which contains methods to show, hide, open categories etc.

```
workspacePlayground.toolbox_.setVisible(false);
```